# React-dates: Styling question to override inline styling

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I want to make styling changes to react-dates, DateRangePicker.

[image]

I want to be able to give paddingBottom and on right as highlighted.

If I see in dev tools it shows me style is given inline so I cannot even override this change

[image]

some guidance is helpful..

Comment: Are you using a custom css file?

Comment: yes I have custom css other controls of the page

Comment: I think adding a css like this would help: `.DateRangePicker_picker{
  paddingBottom : 500px !important;
}` . 500px is just to show you as an example. You can use whatever the number you need.

Comment: If you need you can add other css properties too.

Comment: hey yor suggestion worked just fine. I totally missed that !important part. if you could put as answer I can accept that. Thanks

Comment: Thank You! I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use !important keyword to override the inline CSS. But we have to make sure we are maintaining a custom CSS file for that. In your case,

```
.DateRangePicker_picker{ 
   paddingBottom : 500px !important; 
  }
```

This kind of CSS would be helpful. If you need to specify more about the particular element. You can use extra classes as well.

```
.DateRangePicker_picker DateRangePicker_picker_1{ 
   paddingBottom : 500px !important; 
  }
```

Either you can use the most unique CSS class. If not there will be some glitches in other pages if you are using the same component. Thanks!